# How to use androidx.animation.AnimatorSet?

Tags: android, animation, androidx, android-jetpack, animatorset

I need to use [reverse()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet#reverse()) method of Android AnimatorSet class. The problem is that this method was added only in api 26. But I found reverse method in [source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:animation/animation/src/main/java/androidx/animation/AnimatorSet.java;drc=215c076f9ab14c7b8bbeff535de970e2435ca1d7) in package androidx.animation. And I couldn't find any androidx library that allows to use that AnimatorSet (androidx.animation.AnimatorSet). How can I use that class?

Answer (score 0):

For `Api >=26` you just create an `AnimatorSet` object and after you define the animation you call reverse on it:

```
AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
animatorSet.playSequentially(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(...), ...); 
animatorSet.setDuration(...);
animatorSet.reverse();
animatorSet.start();
```

For older APIs you just reverse the order within the `.ofFloat` methods in your `ObjectAnimators`:

If initially you have `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1)`  you change it to `animator.setFloatValues(1, 0)`

Comment: That's why I am asking, why should I manually change internal animator parameters if someone has already written proper reverse method in androidx?) AnimatorSet this way should support pausing and reversing at any time, and this is not easy to implement with redefining values of internal parameters.

Comment: @KirylTkach Not sure what to tell you. The question was how to use the class. If you're after a library that does this for you, you might want to try going to github and searching their repositories for an animation library in java/kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care it's still in alpha, you can import it from [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core):

````
// To use the Animator APIs
implementation "androidx.core:core-animation:1.0.0-alpha01"
// To test the Animator APIs
androidTestImplementation "androidx.core:core-animation-testing:1.0.0-alpha01"
```
````